# Is there a way to use Drools for Entity weighting?

Tags: optaplanner

I'm using Optaplanner for event planning (~courseschedule example).
Optaplanner requires weight comparator/factory to weight courses, however certain properties might be easier to express via Drools `insertLogical` expressions.

For instance: the course is harder to plan if there are lots of votes to visit it.
That is I have `Votes` as a fact.

Of course I can rearrange the votes and assign them to the `Course` entity, however it seems awkward to have "extra computed elsewhere properties on my entity", and it seems to be way easier to express certain computations via `rule+insertLogical`.

Is it something that is just missing in Optaplanner? Is it intentionally omitted?

Comment: OptaPlanner does **not** require *entity difficulty weight comparison*. It's optional and just a hint for some algorithms. It should only be used when power tweaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a good jira, to support DRL for entity difficulty comparison too.
However, it can't be part of the scoreDrl's as that should be a separate kie session. The difficulty comparison runs once at the beginning (and the the future we might support running it at every step). On the other hand, the score calculation DRL runs at every move.

Personally, I think it might be overkill as weightFactory's are pretty versatile. Create a jira and try to illustrate the use case with the example as well as possible, to change our minds.